# 1C 8.3. Поле не входит в группу

Tags: 1с

Есть такой код в запросе:

```
Запрос = Новый Запрос();
    
    Запрос.Текст="ВЫБРАТЬ СпрНомен.Наименование Как Наименование, СпрНомен.ВидНоменклатуры Как ВидНоменклатуры
    |ИЗ Справочник.Номенклатура КАК СпрНомен
    |СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО ВидНоменклатуры";
    
    ЗапросВыполнить = Запрос.Выполнить().Выбрать();
    
    Пока ЗапросВыполнить.Следующий() Цикл
        Сообщить(ЗапросВыполнить.ВидНоменклатуры);
    КонецЦикла;
```

Пишет: `Поле не входит в группу "СпрНомен.Наименование"`

Почему так происходит, что не хватает?

Answer (score 0):

Использование "*СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО <Поле1>, <Поле2> ...*" требует чтобы при выборке использовалась *агрегатная функция*;

```
ВЫБРАТЬ <Поле1>, <Поле2>, СУММА(<Поле3>) 
ИЗ <Таблица>
СГРУППИРОВАТЬ ПО <Поле1>, <Поле2>
```

Answer (score 0):

При группировке, обязательно должны быть задействованы все поля выборки: поле либо входит в состав группировки, либо по полю должна быть какая-либо агрегатная функция (МИНИМУМ(), МАКСИМУМ(), СУММА() и т.д.)